# PHP code for add attributes to html tag in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

[image: availabitly checking form]

Hi, I want to know what is the php code to add "readonly" attribute to input tag & "disable" to select tag using php code in wordpress ? I am new to wordpress.\

```html
<select name="gdlr-night" id="gdlr-night" readonly> </select>

<input disable>
```

Comment: Hi, kindly accept my answer if it helps you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution for this

```
<input type="text" name="" value="Some text" <?php echo 'readonly'; ?>> <!-- for input -->

<select class="" name="" <?php echo 'disabled'; ?>> <!-- for select -->

</select>
```